# Error "The directory is not empty." when the directory is empy

Tags: c#, .net, windows, ntfs

I'm getting a very intermittent "directory not empty" error trying to delete a directory from c# code but when I look, the directory seems to be empty.

The actual scenario is this: process A invokes process B using a synchronous .Net remoting call, process B deletes the files from the directory and then returns to process A which deletes the directory itself. The disk is a locally attached NTFS Disk (probably SATA).

I'm wondering if there's a possible race Condition with NTFS when you have two processes cooperating in this way, where process B's delete calls have not been completely flushed to the file system?

Of course the more obvious answer is that the directory was genuinely not empty at the time and something else emptied it before I looked at it, but I don't see how this could happen in my current application because there's no other process which would delete the files.

Comment: Have you tried using `Directory.Delete(target_dir, true);` to remove directory and all files recursively?

Comment: have you tried deleting it with the delete key?

Comment: @Weyland, sorry I should have made this clear, yes buy the time I get to it, there's no problem deleting it

Comment: @chridam actually we haven't tried that but I will do. I guess that would give the same results because I know process B has already deleted all the files that are in there

Answer (score 4):

Sure, deleting directories is a perilous adventure on a multi-tasking operating system.  You always have the risk that another process has a file opened.  Failure to delete the directory in your scenario has two primary reasons:

- Particularly trouble-some are the kind of processes that opens the file in a way that does not prevent you from deleting the file but still makes deleting the directory fail with this error.  Search indexers and anti-malware fit this category.  They'll open the file with delete sharing, FileShare.Delete in a .NET program.  Deleting the file works fine.  But the file won't disappear until they close the file handle.  So you can't delete the directory until they do.
- Very hard to diagnose is a process that has the directory selected as its current working directory.  Environment.CurrentDirectory in a .NET program.  Explorer tends to trigger this, just looking at the directory is enough to prevent it from getting deleted.

These mishaps occur totally outside of your control.  You *will* need to deal with them, catching the exception is required.  Little you can do by try again later, there is however no upper limit on how long you'll have to wait.  Renaming the directory and giving it a "trash" name is a good strategy.  Note how the recycle bin in Windows essentially follows this scenario, good for more than just recycling :)

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate the idea that a search indexer or possibly backup program has somehow managed to hold a lock onto the file. The error I get isn't that the directory is locked (which it would be if a process had it set to the CWD) but I can certainly see that there might be some kind of access pattern that would give my symptoms. We already catch exceptions and we're using junk names anyway (this is just a temp file), so it's not causing us a big hassle, just interested to try and get to the bottom of it